# Return PHP array variable-names that are inside a parent array?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have an array of arrays in PHP and I want to access the variable-name of each array (as a string) inside the container array.

Have:

```
$container = array($array1, $array2, $array2);
```

Need:

```
foreach ($container as $anArray) {
    {...some other code...}
    echo variable_name($anArray);  // output: array1 array2 array3
}
```

I'm trying to run a foreach loop to output the name of each array with functions like the following (suggested in the PHP manual):

```
function vname(&$var, $scope=false, $prefix='unique', $suffix='value') {
    if($scope) $vals = $scope;
    else      $vals = $GLOBALS;
    $old = $var;
    $var = $new = $prefix.rand().$suffix;
    $vname = FALSE;
    foreach($vals as $key => $val) {
        if($val === $new) $vname = $key;
    }
    $var = $old;
    return $vname;
}
```

But that function understandably only outputs: anArray  (x3)

I need to output: array1 array2 array3

Any suggestions?

Comment: $vname = $key; is been overwritten everytime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible to retrieve the "names" `array1`, `array2`, `array3` from an array created with `array($array1, $array2, $array3)`. Those *variable names* are gone.

You can make the array *keys* the names though:
    `array('array1' => $array1, 'array2' => $array2, 'array3' => $array3)`
A shortcut for this is `compact('array1', 'array2', 'array3')`.

Answer (score 1):

Make the original array an associative array:

```
$container = array(
  'array1' => $array1,
  'array2' => $array2,
  'array3' => $array3
);
```

Then just print out the keys:

```
foreach($container as $name => $anArray){
  echo $name; //output: array1 array2 array3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I need to output: array1 array2 array3

You can't get name of variable in runtime. Don't waste your time.